# Variable Length Arguments without using stdarg.h

Tags: c, printf

I'm trying to understand and implement a way to handle variable length argument function by checking the stack, but I have not idea on where and how to start. I have found the following links helpful but I still don't quite understand how I would be able to something like this in c for something like a print function.

http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Varargs.html

[Trailing dots (...) within function argument list in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763839/trailing-dots-within-function-argument-list-in-c)

Comment: Why do you want to do this without using `stdarg.h`?

Comment: stdarg.h gives you macroses that facilitates implementation. This is can be easily done without macros on your own.

Comment: I'm trying to understand variable length arguments better and how the OS handles them on the stack. Could you link me to an example spin_eight/

Comment: The OS is not involved.

Answer (score 7):

Look in the [`C Reference Manual by Dennis M. Ritchie`](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/cman.pdf) at the implementation of `printf()` that existed long before `...` and `<stdarg.h>`:

```
printf ( fmt, args )
  char fmt [ ] ;
{
  ...
  int *ap, x, c ;
  ap = &args ; /* argument pointer */
  ...
  for ( ; ; ) {
    while ( ( c = *fmt++ ) != ´%´ ) {
      ...
      switch ( c = *fmt++) {
      /* decimal */
      case ´d ´:
        x = *ap++ ;
        if(x < 0) {
          x = -x;
          if ( x<0 ) { /* is - infinity */
            printf ( "-32768" ) ;
            continue ;
          }
          putchar ( ´-´);
        }
        printd(x);
        continue ;
      ...
      }
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}

printd(n)
{
  int a ;
  if ( a=n/10 )
    printd(a);
  putchar ( n%10 + ´0´ ) ;
}
```

You can disregard the old (AKA K&R) syntax of function and parameter declaration:

```
printf ( fmt, args )
  char fmt [ ] ;
```

and even replace it with a more modern:

```
int printf ( char fmt[], int args )
```

but the idea is the same, you get a pointer to the first optional argument (`args`) directly, as is done in the above code with `ap = &args;`, and then keep incrementing it to get access to further arguments.

Or you can do it indirectly, using the last non-optional argument as the starting point:

```
int printf ( char fmt[], ... )
{
  ...
  int *ap, x, c ;
  ap = &fmt ; /* argument pointer */
  ap++; /* ap now points to first optional argument */
  ...
}
```

This illustrates the mechanism.

Beware, if you write your code like this, it won't be portable and it may even fail work with your compiler.

Comment: Wouldn't this only work on 32 bit systems, and not 64-bit systems? How would you get it to work with 64 bit system? Would you have to compile it using a special flag forcing it to run in a 32-bit format?

Comment: It depends on the kind of the system. If pointers and integers are of the same size, it will work on 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit and whatever systems.

Comment: It won't work on architectures that don't necessarily pass arguments in reverse order on the stack. A platform ABI that allows passing arguments in registers, or a platform which stack grows forward instead of backward, will not work.