# Is there a portable way to implement variadic arguments in C without stdarg.h?

Tags: c, embedded, printf, variadic-functions

I'm working on an existing code base, written in C, which is being compiled using GCC for an arm7tdmi target.  This is embedded code, which runs without an operating system on the target system.

The issue that I'm running into is that the code is using the fantastic [GPL'd embedded printf library, written by Kustaa Nyholm](http://www.sparetimelabs.com/tinyprintf/tinyprintf.php), which uses stdarg.h for variable length arguments.  Without going into too many details, this is causing errors with a commercial preprocessing tool which I need to use.

This is basically the tinyprintf header:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void init_printf(void* putp,void (*putf) (void*,char));
void tfp_printf(char *fmt, ...);
void tfp_sprintf(char* s,char *fmt, ...);
void tfp_format(void* putp,void (*putf) (void*,char),char *fmt, va_list va);
```

Of course, the way the sprintf/printf work they need to have variable arguments.  What I'm wondering is if there is a way to implement this without using stdharg.h and va_list.  Or maybe more to the point, if there is a way to implement variadic arguments in C without requiring stdarg.h.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216260/variable-length-arguments-without-using-stdarg-h) won't work for me, as I am using an ARM target.  In the arm7 calling convention the first four parameters are passed in registers.  Additionally, I need my code to be fairly portable.

I don't know of a way to do this, but maybe the internet has an idea.

Comment: So, your problem is only with the preprocessor and you cannot include `<stdarg.h>` in your code (but your lib may use it internally)? If so, do you use `va_list` etc.? You could modify the header to exclude the `#include` and any declaration of a function using `va_list`. Otherwise, there is no portable way. The stdarg-macros are there exactly to abstract the platform differences away.

Comment: va_list is only used by the tinyprintf library.  Otherwise there are no uses of stdarg.h in the code.  The trouble with using some kind of transformer to remove the declarations that use va_list is that it breaks all the places where those functions are called.

Comment: Maybe `#define tfp_format(a,b,c,d) foo(void)` before the include?

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a good answer (and almost certainly not a portable answer) unless you describe the problem that the commercial preprocessing tool is causing. That said, if your use of the `printf` library is fairly limited, you could come up with 'overloads' that take a specific combination of arguments instead of a variable argument list.  For example, `tfp_printf_i(char *fmt, int i);` and `tfp_printf_si(char *fmt, char const* s, int i);` and so on.  That could be made to work, but it would get tedious pretty quickly...

Comment: @MichaelBurr That's not a bad idea, but I could also simplify it to one function and just accept an array pointer and length as my arguments.  I guess the point of my question was more exploratory.  I am wondering if there's a sneakier way to do this that I just haven't thought about.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `tfp_format()` declaration, you can move the `<stdarg.h>` inclusion from the header to the source file.

If that isn't an option, my guess would be you're out of luck...